# How do I keep Particular ServiceControl Audit db (Raven5) from getting larger and larger in size?

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus, nsb-servicecontrol, ravendb5

We recently upgraded *Particular.ServiceControl.Audit* to **v4.26** and recreated our Audit instance, since from v4.26 and up [new audit instances will bump up RavenDB from 3.5 to 5.4](https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl/releases/tag/4.26.0).

We did this hoping to remedy a problem in 4.25.x where [compacting the audit database](https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/db-compaction) would not free up any disk space.

As it is, the database is still growing really large (3-400GB). To test if the data contained should actually use up all this disk space, we tried to tamper with the `ServiceControl.Audit/AuditRetentionPeriod` config parameter, setting it to a small value like 1 day (before value was 30 days). Naively, maybe, waiting for db to shrink at some point - expecting that retention would somehow influence disk space used. The db file remained the same size (and growing).

The [docs](https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/db-compaction) for compacting the database in ServiceControl only mention the esent based Raven 3.5, but Raven5+ uses Raven's own [Voron storage engine](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/server/storage/storage-engine). There does not seem to be Particular docs describing how to compact the Voron db.

So we tried to follow the [RavenDB docs for compacting the db through Raven Studio](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/studio/database/settings/documents-compression#database-storage-report) after putting the service in maintenance mode. As the screenshot shows, this operation stopped or stalled very shortly after initializing (disregard time elapsed, as we actually left it running for several hours).

[image: screenshot]

We tried this several times with no luck. We can see that the disk containing the specific db has zero reads or writes, so it is definitely stalled in some way. Pressing the "Abort" button also got stuck every time, after which we resolved to simply restarting the entire service (which then seemed to bring the db back to normal operation).

So the question is: how do we keep the audit db from growing indefinitely? We can't at any point see it not growing or staying the same size, causing SSD disk costs to grow in expenses.